# What is the best way to change the sprite used to display an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I have an object that changes its display based on which way it's facing. The object takes a 4x4 grid of frames, and uses each row of 4 frames as an animation for each state.

Currently, I'm loading these into separate sprites using:

```
def create_animation(image_grid, start_idx, end_idx):
    frames = []
    for frame in image_grid[start_idx:end_idx]:
        frames.append(pyglet.image.AnimationFrame(frame, 0.1))
    return pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.image.Animation(frames))
```

and then adding the sprite that should be displayed to a `batch` to be drawn, and removing it when it shouldn't be drawn.

However, reading the documentation, I saw this:

> `Sprite.batch`
>
> The sprite can be migrated from one batch to another, or removed from its batch (for individual drawing). Note that this can be an expensive operation.

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do without the performance hit of switching the individual sprites in and out of batches?

Comment: You could try simply flipping the `visible` property of the sprites when needed, and leaving them in the batch. Checking the `visible` boolean to see if the sprite should be drawn should be faster than swapping them out of batches.

Comment: @Josh That is what I ended up doing, care to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the image as a TextureGrid:

```
    img = pyglet.resource.image("obj_grid.png")
    img_grid = pyglet.image.ImageGrid(   
        img,
        4,  # rows, direction
        4  # cols, frames of the animation
    )
    texture_grid = pyglet.image.TextureGrid(img_grid)  # this is the one you actually use
```

Create your (single) sprite:

```
    batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()  # unless you already have a batch
    my_object = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(
        img=texture_grid[0, 0],  # [row, col] for starting grid /frame
        batch=batch
    )
```

Determine/change direction ("row", I'm guessing based on input?).

Loop over 0-3 ("col"/frame of the animation ):

```
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(change_frame, 0.1, my_object)

    def change_frame(dt, my_object):  # pyglet always passes 'dt' as argument on scheduled calls
        my_object.col += 1
        my_object.col = my_object.col & 3 #  or my_object.col % 3 if its not a power of 2
```

And set the frame manually:

```
    current_frame = self.texture_grid[self.row, self.col].get_texture()
    my_object._set_texture(current_frame)
```

No additional calls to draw(), no messing with the batch(). Everything is drawn as usual, but you change the texture it draws as you wish :)